# actionscript rss embedded in html

Tags: html, actionscript-3, actionscript, rss, embed

I'm new to actionscript and have some question:

i've written an rss reader using AS 3.0 in CS 5.5

when i press ctrl+Enter it reads my rss fead,

but when i publish it in html it just stucks on the picture(shown on the stage) and does nothing + shows the error of sandbox violation

i've spend all the day reading the documentation and understood that it's something with the domain restrictions or something like that, but still can't understand what to do exactly, can you please help me

this is the code of my swf file

russian.swf

```
var news_title:Array = new Array ();
var news_descr:Array = new Array ();
var news_pubdate:Array = new Array ();

var rus = "http://news.yandex.ua/index.rss";


test (rus,txt_descr,txt_title);

function test (link,txt_descr,txt_title)

{
var rssLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(link));

rssLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, end_rssLoad);

function end_rssLoad(rss_data:Event)
{
    var rss_file:XML = new XML(rss_data.target.data);

    for each (var item:XML in rss_file.channel.item)
    {
        news_title.push(item.title);
        news_descr.push(item.description);
        news_pubdate.push(item.pubDate);

    }

    show_rss();
}


function show_rss()
{
    //number of news in rss field
    var i:Number = 0;

    //number of loops before update the field
    var n:Number = 0;

    function assign_rss_textBox()
    {
        txt_title.htmlText = news_title[i];

        var blank_height = txt_descr.height;

        txt_descr.htmlText = news_descr[i];
        txt_descr.autoSize = "center";
        txt_descr.y = txt_descr.y + (blank_height - txt_descr.height) / 2;

        i+=1;
        if (i >= news_title.length)
        {
            i=0;
            n+=1;
            if (n > 2)
            {
                clearInterval(delay_assign_rss_textBox);
            }
        }
    }

    assign_rss_textBox();

    var delay_assign_rss_textBox = setInterval(assign_rss_textBox,500);
}

}
```

and this is the code of html page

```
<html>
<body>
<object width="600" height="125">
<param name="movie" value="russian.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<embed src="russian.swf" quality=high width="600" height="125" ">
</embed>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly identified, this is a cross-domain security issue caused by the fact that you are trying to load data from another domain into your Flash file. If you look at the [`crossdomain.xml`](http://news.yandex.ua/crossdomain.xml) on the domain on which the feed is stored, you will see that it only allows requests from the domain itself.

If you don't have any control over that cross domain policy, which I presume you don't, the usual solution would be to create a server-side proxy on your own domain to read the data and expose it to your SWF. [This article](http://xmlrpcflash.mattism.com/proxy_info.php) explains the process quite nicely and includes an example script.

There's also a solution explained [here](http://scottrockers.com/blog/resources/flash-information/workaround-solution-to-flash-error-2044-unhandled-securityerror-and-error-2048-security-sandbox-violation) which involves mirroring the feed in [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/myfeeds?gsessionid=9EI9AFDrptvF_QgFQ3EC1g) and consuming it from there (presumably its cross domain policy is more lenient) rather than directly from the source feed.